# Is Angular-Seed necessary for a Java EE app?

Tags: java, javascript, angularjs

I have a Java EE project using Spring MVC and maybe some JSP files (or plain html not sure yet)

I will use angular.js for the frontend. do I need anything like angular-seed or angular-sproud? OR these frameworks are only for javascript only applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS is a frontend framework, angular-seed and angular-sprout are just examples of how it used, quick start projects.

In your case, the app will most likely use Spring and Java on the backend and have so called one page dynamic JavaScript frontend built in AnglularJS.

Have a look at Rob Harrop's demo project that integrates both technologies, I found it to be really helpful.

[Spring MVC REST and AngularJS](https://github.com/robharrop/spring-angularjs)

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same predicament some time back. The short answer is depends!.. you do not need Angular-Seed to front-end a Java EE app. But you do need some starting point. The problem is that AngularSeed is not really a servlet that can be served up as an SPA. 
On the other hand, if you would like to build a front-end *completely* decoupled from the server then maybe AngularSeed will work for you.

I've written about this [here](http://nayidisha.com/techblog/angular-js-from-a-different-angle)

I began with AngularSeed and was kind of disillusioned. Using a Servlet to serve up the  Angular SPA is so much better.